# Vim Fold at a specific Text Block

Tags: vim, syntax, indentation

I am quite new to Vim folds. But it looks very interesting. I have a comment block like this. (semicolon is a comment operator).

```
; START ANALYSIS
;
; Check for validity of data file
; ....
; Text 
; Text...etc
;
; END ANALYSIS
```

How can I fold this? What `foldmethod` work best for it?

I have tried `foldmethod` of `indent` and `expr` without much success. `syntax` foldmethod looks intimidating.

Can anyone help? (btw, the filetype is `idlang`).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as this is the only block you want folded, this is easy.

#### option A

One way is to redefine the foldmarkers (`{{{` / `}}}` by default) to use the text from your block:

```
setlocal foldmethod=marker foldmarker=START\ ANALYSIS,END\ ANALYSIS
```

#### option B

You could also use a fold expression and then do a string (or regexp) comparison:

```
setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=getline(v:lnum)==';\ START\ ANALYSIS'?'>1':getline(v:lnum)==';\ END\ ANALYSIS'?'<1':'='
```

That conditional looks difficult, also because it is written in-line. As an expanded function, it would look like:

```
function! FoldAnalysis( line )
    if a:line == '; START ANALYSIS'
        " A level 1 fold starts here; cp :help fold-expr
        return '>1'
    elseif a:line == '; END ANALYSIS'
        " A level 1 fold ends here
        return '<1'
    else
        " Use fold level from previous line
        return '='
    endif
endfunction
setlocal foldmethod=expr foldexpr=FoldAnalysis(getline(v:lnum))
```

#### option C

If want to have this folding *on top* of the original filetype's folding, you have to go with what the filetype defines (often syntax-based), and extend that.

#### installing

To make any of this persistent, put the commands in `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/idlang.vim`

Comment: This is exactly what I wanted. Can you please help me understand the regex  `getline(v:lnum)==';\ START\ ANALYSIS'?'>1'`. Thanks @Ingo.

Comment: @Cricrazy: I've expanded the short form into a full function; that is much easier to understand. Please upvote + accept if this suits your needs!

Comment: That is exactly what I wanted. Your answer and this [vimcast](http://vimcasts.org/episodes/writing-a-custom-fold-expression/) helped me to create this advanced folding. I really appreciate you taking time to explain it. Marked as a answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Since there is no syntax or indentation you cannot use these fold methods four your comments. Instead you could use marker

```
; START ANALYSIS {{{
;
; Check for validity of data file
; ....
; Text 
; Text...etc
;
; END ANALYSIS }}}
```

where `{{{` and `}}}` would be your marker. Then you can `set foldmethod=marker`.

Use `:help marker` for more information.

Comment: thanks. Unfortunately, I can't add this markers. It may require to change in lots of files. I was hoping that `syntax` foldmethod would somehow allow me to fold this block.

Answer (score 0):

Just select the lines you wants to fold by using mouse selection or normal selection, then type `zf` for folding the selected lines and `zo` for unfolding the the same.

Comment: Thanks. I am aware of Manual foldmethod. Will it remember it for future or for other files with same filetype?